# Spring boot: push message to specific topic for each request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I am using pub sub integration with spring boot, for which my configuration class look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class PubSubConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.pubsub.topic.name}")
    private String topicName;

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "MyOutputChannel")
    public PubSubMessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, topicName);
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "MyOutputChannel")
    public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {
        void sendToPubsub(String attribute);
    }

}
```

So now, I was calling only sendToPubSub method which add payload into topic from my app, like this:

```
@Autowired
private PubSubConfiguration.PubsubOutboundGateway outboundGateway;

// used line in my code wherever is needed. 
outboundGateway.sendToPubsub(jsonInString);
```

The above code is just meant for one topic which i loaded from application property file.

But now I wanted to make my topic name is dynamically added into messageSender, how to do that.

Comment: did you find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 2):

To override the default topic you can use the GcpPubSubHeaders.TOPIC header.

```java
final Message<?> message = MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(msg.getPayload())
        .setHeader(GcpPubSubHeaders.TOPIC, "newTopic").build();
```

and modify your `sendToPubsub(Message<byte[]> message)` to use message as input.

[Refer for more information](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/2.0.2/reference/html/index.html#outbound-channel-adapter)

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a [BeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) to generate a PubSubMessageHandler Bean given a topic name. [PubSubMessageHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/pubsub/integration/outbound/PubSubMessageHandler.html) also has a setTopic() method, which may be of use.